# PowerShell to list Exchange mailbox that have Full Access delegate permission more than 1 person

Tags: powershell, active-directory, office365, exchange-server

I need to know which Exchange User Mailbox is currently accessed by more than one person other than the user display name itself. Here is my code:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Where-Object { ($_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess") -and ($_.IsInherited -eq $false) -and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and -not ($_.User -like '*Discovery Management*') } |
   Select @{Name="User Name";expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.tostring()).displayname}}, Identity,AccessRights,PrimarySMTPAddress | Export-Csv C:\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What needs fixing here?

Comment: "or fix the above", what problem is occuring with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although using `-and -not` is correct, I'd not say it's not the most elegant approach as there are contrary operators to `-like` and `-eq` (which was suggested by [@Paxz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6404133/paxz) in now deleted comments). Your `where` statement could be modified to something like:

```
 Where-Object { ($_.AccessRights -like "*FullAccess*") -and (-not $_.IsInherited) -and ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and ($_.User -notlike '*Discovery Management*') }
```

#### Changes I made:

```
# from
($_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess")
# to 
($_.AccessRights -like "*FullAccess*")
```

to include the situation when user has one or more access entry in `AccessRight` (although I'm not sure if it's needed in real life). Your code would filter `{FullAccess, ReadPermission}` as it's not equal to `FullAccess`.

```
# from
($_.IsInherited -eq $false) 
# to 
(-not $_.IsInherited)
```

Why? More elegant. `IsInherited` is boolean value you can directly use `-not`.

```
# from
-and -not ($_.User -like "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")
# to
-and ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF")
```

Why? `like`/`notlike` is not needed here, you can use `-ne` directly.

```
# from 
-and -not ($_.User -like '*Discovery Management*')
# to
-and ($_.User -notlike '*Discovery Management*')
```

similar as above but I'm not sure what values are possible here so I haven't changed to `-ne`.

---

Also, in your `Select-Object` you use `PrimarySMTPAddress` which won't work as permission entry doesn't have such parameter. You'll have to use similar approach as you used for `User Name` (also, I don't think that `.ToString()` is necessary in that case):

```
@{Name="PrimarySMTPAddress";expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user).PrimarySMTPAddress}}
```

Comment: Cool, many thanks Robby for your sharing and the explanations, I appreciate it muchly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below to list exchange mailbox that have full access delegate permission:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Where-Object { ($_.AccessRights -like "*FullAccess*") -and (-not $_.IsInherited) -and ($_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF") -and ($_.User -notlike '*Discovery Management*') } |
Select @{Name="User Name";expression={(Get-Recipient $_.user.tostring()).displayname}}, Identity,AccessRights,PrimarySMTPAddress | Export-Csv C:\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks Yuki for the assistance in this matter.